# Why does the following expression in Javascript with logical AND operator is giving syntax Error?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, logical-and

While the expression is evaluating as expected for `1 && {}` giving `{}` as the answer, however when I flip the operands to make it `{} && 1` it gives syntax error.

```
452:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&&'
```

I was expecting 1 as the result in the latter case. The same behavior is replicated with the || (OR) operator.

Comment: Because when a statement starts with `{`, it is a **block statement**, not an object initializer.

Comment: You can fix it by doing `({}) && 1`

Comment: *(For small values of “fix”)*

Answer (score -5):

1. 1 && {}: In this case, 1 is a truthy value, so the evaluation
   continues to the second operand, {}. Since {} is an object and is
   considered truthy, the result of the expression is {}.
2. {} && 1: Here, {} is an object and is considered truthy, so the
   first operand is truthy. However, when it comes to the second
   operand, 1, there is a syntactical issue. In JavaScript, the logical
   AND operator (&&) expects both operands to be expressions or values
   that can be evaluated. However, 1 is a single token, and it cannot
   be used as an operand for the logical AND operator without wrapping
   it in parentheses. Hence, you're seeing a syntax error.

Comment: the issue isn't with `1` it's with `{}` ... `"some string" && 1` works fine for example

Comment: “The logical AND operator expects both operands to be expressions or values that can be evaluated” — are you saying the number `1` isn’t an expression or value that can be evaluated?